# What happens when you mix Lysol and bleach?

Tags: chemistry

My mother just forwarded an email to all her contacts (thanks, mom), warning us of the dangers of mixing Lysol and bleach together. Here's most the content, translated from French:

> **Bleach and Lysol, a lethal mix**
>
> If the experience of my friend can be of any help... Read her email!
>
> Here is my latest bad experience that I want to share with you. It might be useful to you. On January 2nd 2011, I was finishing to wash the previous evening's dishes when I had family come over for dinner. As I was finishing, I thought of using a bit of bleach to disinfect the sink.
>
> Since I had very little bleach left, I went to fetch my Lysol and poured the bleach I had left with the Lysol. This was a terrible mix that you should never attempt to recreate. Two minutes later, I could barely breathe and thirty minutes later I was at the hospital where I received care from the ambulance and at the hospital.
>
> The doctor told me that it would have taken very little more for me pass away. An accident by lack of knowledge can happen quite fast and can sometimes be lethal.

As a general rule, I'm skeptical of whatever I read in chain mails so I googled excerpts of the text. Unsurprisingly, I found [an almost exact](http://mytheourealite.com/eau-de-javel-et-lysol-melange-mortel/) match as the first search result. The only difference is that the year changed, from 2011 in the email I received to 2009 on the blog page so it's undoubtedly a chain letter. By the way, that page is also the first result when you google "eau de javel lysol" ("bleach lysol", in French).

A search on the web returns unhelpful results, with the average content farms contradicting each other and offering no trustworthy source.

As any chemist would know, bleach is [sodium hypochlorite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaClO) and, from a quick search, it would seem the active agent in Lysol is [benzalkonium chloride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzalkonium_chloride) but I can't find anything on the interaction of those two compounds either. From a quick look at the two compounds, I would be surprised to see any spectacular interaction between the two of them though.

So, does anyone know what happens when you mix Lysol and bleach?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

According to this document from the Utah health department: [Common Cleaning Products May Be Dangerous When Mixed](https://health.utah.gov/enviroepi/activities/NTSIP/Common%20Cleaning%20Products%20Can%20Be%20Dangerous%20When%20Mixed.pdf), dangerous gasses are produced.

More generally, [The Chlorine Institute, Inc.](http://www.chlorineinstitute.org) advises that one not "mix Sodium Hypochlorite (bleach) with ANY other chemical unless adequate engineering controls and personal protective equipment (PPE) are in place" in their [Avoiding Accidental Mixing of Sodium Hypochlorite](http://www.chlorineinstitute.org/files/FileDownloads/Avoiding%20Accidental%20Mixing%20of%20Sodium%20Hypochlorite%20%2D%20Guidance%20Document%2020100323%201.pdf) document. They also have a [Sodium Hypochlorite Incompatibility Chart (English Version)](http://www.chlorineinstitute.org/pub/2ca904fc-2354-d714-51a7-2cfd6c4de8e6) which lists the bad things which can happen when mixing bleach with other chemicals.

Thanks to Fabian in the comments, he noted that benzalkonium chloride is a quarternary ammonium salt which, according to the incompatibility chart, will release chlorine or other noxious gases when mixed.

Additionally, according to the makers of Lysol ( [Reckitt Benckiser Inc.](http://www.reckittprofessional.com/) ) in their [Material Safety Data Sheet](http://www.rbnainfo.com/MSDS/US/LYSOL-Brand-Multi-Surface-Cleaner-Complete-Clean-Pourable-US-English.pdf), they say under point 10: "DO NOT MIX WITH BLEACH" - note the nice big bold letters.

Comment: As far as I found, Lysol contains neither ammonia nor acid, so those reactions don't explain this specific case.

Comment: The linked incompatibility chart explains it, as benzalkonium chloride is a quarternary ammonium salt, which is listed in that chart.

Comment: @MadScientist see Cornell Univ. document "Bleach can safely be mixed with quaternary ammonium compounds" http://www.sheltermedicine.vet.cornell.edu/resources/documents/UsingBleach.pdf ; Effect of a Benzalkonium Chloride Surfactant-Sodium Hypochlorite Combination http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26577873 ; as well as patents for quanternary ammonium hypochlorites https://www.google.com/patents/US2256958, and Lysol products the containing both compounds https://www.thecloroxcompany.com/products/ingredients-inside/en-ca/clorox/cloroxdisinfectingbleachfoamer/